# How to get an unique id from sql server

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows-server

Is there a way for a normal user (client-side) without elevated privileges (no special database permissions, local administrator, or any of the sort) on the server to get any kind of unique ID from a server (MAC address, database installation ID, server hardware ID) or anything of the kind?

Basically I am looking for an ID to verify the installation. I know I can do it by writing some sort of ID into registry and the database to install server-side, but is there a way to do it without installing anything? The minimum requirements for that is that I get that from MySQL and SQL Server with Linux and Windows.

My current research suggests that there is no such thing. As seen in the comment below:

> I think any answer is going to require xp_cmdshell since unique
>   hardware information is not exposed directly to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can get hardware details directly from Sql-Server . it may possible throw the other programs which can contribute with both sql-server and your system hardware .

there is a pre-define function in sql server which will give you unique and random id .

```
create table TableName
(
   id varchar(max) default newid()
)
```

Comment: That I know but that does not get me closer to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Best I can find is that you can use `file_guid` from `sys.database_files`.  You only need to be in the public role to do that and that should be unique per DB.  If you create or remove database files, you'll run into trouble, and it doesn't do anything about verifying that you're on the same server.

Note that if your DB was created prior to SQL Server 2005, this value will be null since it didn't exist.